# Qual a diferença de Phonegap e Ionic?

Tags: ionic, mobile, app, cross-platform

Estava revendo algumas frameworks de Cross-Platform e descobri o Ionic, que usa o Html, Javascript e CSS para desenvolvimento de aplicativos híbridos.

Então, qual a diferença do Ionic e do Phonegap?
Por que utilizar um e não o outro? Qual projeto é mais indicado para determinado frameworks ?

Comment: Há um tópico bem interessante no site da DevMedia explicando sobre, segue o link: https://www.devmedia.com.br/xamarin-ionic-e-cordova-conheca-o-que-sao-e-as-principais-diferencas/37690